# How to use addErrorHandlers in Alexa ASK SDK V2

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm attempting to upgrade my skill from V1 to ASK SDK V2. I'm having trouble using the `addErrorHandlers` function on the `StandardSkillBuilder`. When I throw an error in my intent, my custom error handler is never called. I'm not sure how to use it.

**index.ts**

```typescript
import { SkillBuilders } from 'ask-sdk';
import { LambdaHandler } from 'ask-sdk-core/dist/skill/factory/BaseSkillFactory';

// import intents
import LaunchIntent from './alexa-intents/launch.intent';
import CustomErrorHandler from './alexa-intents/custom-error-handler';

function buildAlexaLambdaHandler(): LambdaHandler {
    return SkillBuilders.standard()
        .addRequestHandlers(
            new LaunchIntent()
        )
        .addErrorHandlers(new CustomErrorHandler())
        .lambda();
}

export const handler = buildAlexaLambdaHandler();
```

**launch.intent.ts** (throw a test error)

```typescript
import { HandlerInput, RequestHandler } from 'ask-sdk';
import { Response } from 'ask-sdk-model'

export default class LaunchIntent implements RequestHandler {
    canHandle(handlerInput: HandlerInput): boolean {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    }

    handle(handlerInput: HandlerInput): Response {
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
        const deviceId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.deviceId;
        if (deviceId) {
            console.log('throwing error');
            throw new Error('test error');
        }
        return responseBuilder
            .speak('welcome')
            .getResponse();
    }
}
```

**custom-error-handler.ts** (attempt to catch the test error)

```typescript
import { HandlerInput, ErrorHandler } from 'ask-sdk';
import { Response } from 'ask-sdk-model';

export default class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    canHandle(handlerInput: HandlerInput): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    handle(handlerInput: HandlerInput, error: Error): Response {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        const deviceId = handlerInput.context.System.device.deviceId;
        console.dir(error);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak('there was an error')
            .getResponse();
    }
}
```

I'm running my skill locally using `bespoken-tools` `LambdaServer`:

```typescript
import * as bst from 'bespoken-tools';

const server = new bst.LambdaServer('./src/index', 10000, true);
server.start(() => console.log('[init.dev]: server started and listening on port 10000!'));
```

In my console logs, I see my console message from the launch intent handler "throwing error", but then I never see the `CustomErrorHandler` called or any console logs from it. In the Alexa Developer Console simulator, I get "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" because no response was ever added by the `CustomerErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

[Someone on the Alexa forums helped me find my issue.](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/198951/how-to-use-adderrorhandlers-in-v2-ask-sdk.html)

Basically, my `CustomErrorHandler` was accessing the `deviceId` improperly and throwing an error itself. After changing the line in the `CustomErrorHandler` to this, the issue was resolved and the error handler worked as intended.

```typescript
const deviceId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.deviceId;
```

instead of

```typescript
const deviceId = handlerInput.context.System.device.deviceId;
```

Something else that might be good practice is to have a backup error handler to catch errors in your error handlers that simply prints out the error to avoid anything going wrong in the backup handler.